# How to create/migrate Elixir Phoenix Docker image on Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework, heroku-postgres

I am trying to figure out how to run Elixir Phoenix on Heroku using Docker. I am pretty much using this Dockerfile: (https://github.com/jpiepkow/phoenix-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile)

```
# ---- Build Base Stage ----
FROM elixir:1.9.1-alpine AS app_builder
RUN apk add --no-cache=true \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    git \
    make \
    musl-dev
RUN mix do local.hex --force, local.rebar --force   

# ---- Build Deps Stage ----
FROM app_builder as deps
COPY mix.exs mix.lock ./
ARG MIX_ENV=prod
ENV MIX_ENV=$MIX_ENV
RUN mix do deps.get --only=$MIX_ENV, deps.compile

# ---- Build Release Stage ----
FROM deps as releaser
RUN echo $MIX_ENV
COPY config ./config
COPY lib ./lib
COPY priv ./priv
RUN mix release && \
    cat mix.exs | grep app: | sed -e 's/ app: ://' | tr ',' ' ' | sed 's/ //g' > app_name.txt

# ---- Final Image Stage ----
FROM alpine:3.9 as app
RUN apk add --no-cache bash libstdc++ openssl
ENV CMD=start
COPY --from=releaser ./_build .
COPY --from=releaser ./app_name.txt ./app_name.txt
CMD ["sh","-c","./prod/rel/$(cat ./app_name.txt)/bin/$(cat ./app_name.txt) $CMD"]
```

I have pushed to Heroku and the app is running but when I try to using database things that's when it blows up. The logs say the database needs to be migrated, which makes sense since I haven't done it. But now I realize I'm not sure how to do that when `mix` is not available and I'm using Docker.

Does anyone know how to create and migrate postgres heroku when deployed with Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `lib/my_app/release.ex` mentioned in https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html#ecto-migrations-and-custom-commands

bash into Heroku release container (this is different behavior from, for example, a Rails app):

```
heroku run bash --app my_app
```

Two options:

**1**

```
./prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app start_iex
```

Then run

```
MyApp.Release.migrate
```

**2**

```
./prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app eval ""MyApp.Release.migrate"
```